# C-style cast to C++-style cast(s) - when is it not possible to perform const and then static/reinterpret?

Tags: c++, casting, language-lawyer

The [standard](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast) specifies that C-style cast is essentially equal to successive tries of different cast orders of `static_cast`, `reinterpret_cast` and `const_cast` (with a few edge cases with access specifiers).

Sometimes, a static/reinterpret cast needs to be performed and then a const cast needs to be performed after to change the necessary qualifiers, which the standard specifies:

> c) static_cast (with extensions) followed by const_cast;
> ...
>
> e) reinterpret_cast followed by const_cast.

Are there any examples where we can't first perform `const_cast` and then `reinterpret/static_cast` to get the same result? Or is the order imposed by the standard arbitrary?

A simple example:

```cpp
int * const * x {}; // pointer to a const pointer to int
reinterpret_cast<double**>(x); // fails because we need to change qualifiers
const_cast<double**>(x); // fails because we need to bitcast
const_cast<double**>(reinterpret_cast<double* const*>(x)); // successful
reinterpret_cast<double**>(const_cast<int**>(x)); // successful
```

Comment: As far as I understand, for built-in types doing `const_cast` first or last would have the same effect. For user defined types, maybe there are some edge cases. As you should avoid C style cast, in practice you will decide yourself which cast to use anyway.

Comment: @Phil1970 yes, this was a purely curiosity-based question rather than one based off of real practical needs on my side. I agree that casts are dangerous to perform in the first place and C style cast especially should be minimized in any code base.

Comment: @Phil1970 For UDT you don't `const_cast`, you can only construct another instance (ctor call) w/ `static_cast`.